# Problem with Superfish menu

Tags: css, superfish

See link:
http://www.advertisesolutions.com/beta/4kitchens.html

Cannot understand why there is a gap below the main menu and the submenus and the menu for Profile->Profile Setting has a problem with the height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The profile setting has a height problem because you set it to 33px height and it spans two lines...

change .main-menu li to:

```
.main-menu li {
      background:#ff6633;
      height:auto;
}
```

and .main-menu li:hover to:

```
.main-menu li:hover {
      background:#ff6633;
      height:auto;
}
```

To remove the gap change:

```
.main-menu li:hover ul, .main-menu li.sfHover ul {
left: 0;
top: 2.5em;
z-index: 99;
```

}

to:

```
.main-menu li:hover ul, .main-menu li.sfHover ul {
left: 0;
top: 2.2em;
z-index: 99;
```

}

Your top value was just too large and positioning the sub menu too low.

Comment: Got that but the height of the whole bar is too much. I thought I had that fixed.

Comment: Since there are multiples of each class in the CSS, could you tell me which lines to add that to?

Comment: Looks like you found that out already because its fixed... I also found the problem with the gap and edited my answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
.main-menu li li {
  position:relative;
  top:-10px;
}
```

You want to target the second level of your menu, then change the top:-10px value accordingly until gap is gone.

Negative number is important! (negative for gap fixes, positive for overlaps)

Comment: Dude, question almost 3 YRS old. why reply?